# How do I reference rows instead of columns in apps script for google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function email(){
var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange()
var email = rng.getValues()[0]; GmailApp.sendEmail(email[0], email[1], email[2]);
}
```

I used this code (which I found online) to send an email from Google Sheets via Gmail. It works perfectly but only if the 3 values (i.e. recipient, subject, message) are in 3 cells in a single row.

I would like the same function to work if the 3 values are in 3 rows in a single column instead. (e.g. A:1, A:2, A:3 etc etc)

I know this must be simple but I’m totally new to code! Could somebody please show me how this should be written and why? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google App Scripts `getValues()` will return a 2d array.  First dimension being the rows, second being the columns, as it were.

In your code. You are asking your script to only get row index 0

```
var email = rng.getValues()[0]
```

Therefore you will need to remove index 0 on your email variable.

```
var email = rng.getValues()
```

Then update your indexing of email variable accordingly:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(email[0][0], email[1][0], email[2][0]);
```